# php - unable to load SSRS Report

Tags: php, reporting-services

Hi i am trying to load a RDL file and show its output to the user using php.In this rdl file we dont need to pass any parameters.

I have used this link http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/

I have rdl file named "Daily Sales By YearWeek"  in my Reports folder

Here is my code :

```
<?php


require_once 'SSRSReport.php';


define("UID", "####");
define("PASWD", "####");
define("SERVICE_URL", "####");
define("REPORT", "/Reports/Daily Sales By YearWeek");

try

{
    $ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
echo"<br>testion12.....<br>";
    $executionInfo = $ssrs_report->LoadReport2(REPORT, NULL);
echo"<br>testion3.....<br>";
    if($executionInfo->CredentialsRequired)

    {

        echo "The report data source ". $executionInfo->DataSourcePrompts[0]->Name . "Requires credentials";

    }

    else

    {

        echo "Report data source does not require credentials";

    }

}

catch(SSRSReportException $serviceException)

{
echo"error";

    echo $serviceExcprion->GetErrorMessage();

}
```

When i run this code i am getting this as my ouput

```
testion12.....
error
```

the above two error comes sice because i have echoed those things for debugging.
Actually the report is not loaded in LoadReport2 method.

Please can someone help me to figure out whats the problem?

Comment: could you resolve your issue?